# Kunena Form button not visible in IE10

Tags: joomla

I've recently installed Kunena form on our website and everything seems to be working except I am unable to see the form buttons such as `submit`, `preview`, and `cancel` in `IE10`.  I can hover over them and highlight them but cannot see them.  Does anyone know of a way to fix this issue?  I've tried compatibility mode but that did not work.  The only thing that did work is if I go into F-12 and go into IE9 compatibility. Hope the image below helps somewhat.

[image: btns]

Comment: As a developer I've run into a scenerio where leaving console.log(myVar); in my javascript code broke IE.  I would do a quick search using your browser of your source code to be sure that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put your *compatibility* mode meta tag?  In your active template, if you place the below before all of your other inline meta and  statements are you still missing the buttons?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```